# Software that can produce a pronunciation of a word in .ogg format, based on the IPA?

Tags: windows-7, speech-synthesis

I'd just like to know if there's any pieces of software that can generate the pronunciation of a word (without me having to pronounce it myself, that is) based on its [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) and save it as an .ogg file.

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit SP1

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I have found  is [this](https://gist.github.com/tantalor/202523) script from [that](http://johntantalo.com/blog/ipa-tts-bookmarklet/) webpage where the author uses the [AT&T Natural Voices Text to Speech engine](http://www2.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php) that is able to parse a subset of correctly formatted IPA.

It does currently not work, as the hardcoded IP address has changed and a simple exchange of the IP shows only a warning.

However, by inputting

```
<phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="ˌɪntəˈnæʃnəl"> </phoneme>
```

on the AT&T page, you get some result, which is ok for this word. The output is in wav, which you can download. It would need to be converted to ogg for if you wish. I'm sure you can use their [API](http://developer.att.com/apis/speech) for your project. It may be free for your use case.

On a different note, [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/is-it-hard-for-software-speech-synthesisers-to-handle-ipa-if-so-why) is some background on using espeak (that is on linux) on [linguists](http://linguists.stackexchange.com)